# How to get the timestamp for the sub directories recursively

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to get the time stamp of sub directories recursively and write to a new file. Below is the sample script that i wrote. But it is not happening recursively.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=`date +'%d%m%Y'`
Year=`date +%Y`
Temp_Path=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/
File_Path=/bishare/DLSFTP/
cd $File_Path
echo $Year
find /bishare/DLSFTP/$Year*  -type d | ls -lrt > $Temp_Path/New_Bishare_File_Data_$CURRENT_DATE.txt
```

Comment: Note that the `cd` operation is moot; it does no particular harm, but given that you tell `find` to use an absolute path, it isn't necessary either.  You should probably use `find "$File_Path/$Year"* …` to make proper use of the variable.  Otherwise, if anything moves, you have to change two lines in the script instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ls` ignores stdin.  Instead, try:

```
find /bishare/DLSFTP/$Year* -type d -exec ls -dlrt {} +
```

#### Discussion

As an example, let's run `ls -d` with no arguments and no stdin:

```
$ ls -d
.
```

Now, let's supply the name of a directory, `A`, on stdin:

```
$ echo A | ls -d
.
```

As you can see, `ls` ignored stdin.  Now, let's supply the name `A` on the command line:

```
$ ls -d A
A
```

This succeeds.  `ls` returns the name of the directory `A`.

In the `find` command, `-exec ls -lrt {} +` tells `find` to put the names of directories it finds on the command line following `ls -lrt` and then to execute `ls`.  This is what you need.

Note also that `ls -lrt` will report on the files in the directories.  To only show information on the directories, use `-d`: `ls -dlrt`.

#### Alternative 1

If the `find` on your system supports `-printf`, then we can eliminate the use of `ls` and get a custom format for the output (hat tip: [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)).  For example:

```
find .  -type d -printf '%t %p\n'
```

`%t` prints the time stamp and `%p` prints the name of the directory.  This is supported by GNU `find`.

#### Alternative 2

Although it lacks the formatting flexibility of `ls` or `find -printf`, there is another option: `find` has a `-ls` action:

```
find .  -type d -ls
```

This too may require GNU `find`.

Comment: Now i am getting time stamp for all the files not the directories.

Comment: If you just want to see the directories, add, like in my examples above, the `-d` option to `ls`:  `find /bishare/DLSFTP/$Year* -type d -exec ls -dlrt {} +`

Comment: Rather than `-exec ls`, look at `-printf` for getting the output in properly machine-readable format.

Comment: @tripleee Excellent suggestion!  I added a printf solution.  It is unfortunate that some finds, such as the one on [Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html), don't support `-printf`.